# How to put data in WPf Data Grid specific cell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

i m using DataGrid in WPF

I want to put some specific string in some specific cell .  How can we do this.

I am putting value this way .

//pPredicate is a string variable havign some value 
// i m assigning in a particualr cell (3rd col)

```
         if (GetCell(3).Content is TextBlock)
            {
                ((TextBlock)(GetCell(3).Content)).Text = pPredicate;
            }
            else // TextBox
            {
                ((TextBox)(GetCell(3).Content)).Text = pPredicate;
            }



private DataGridCell GetCell(int column)
        {
            DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow();

            if (rowContainer != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

                // Try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized.
                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    // Now try to bring into view and retreive the cell.
                    customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.Columns[column]);
                    cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                }
                return cell;
            }
            return null;
        }

       private DataGridRow GetRow()
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_currentRowIndex);
            if (row == null)
            {
                // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
                customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.UpdateLayout();
                customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ScrollIntoView(customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.Items[_currentRowIndex]);
                row = (DataGridRow)customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_currentRowIndex);
            }
            return row;
        }

       private T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
```

the problem in top most statmetnts is the row is in edit mode the grid contains textbox while otherwise grid contains textblock. When i m putting value in textblock it does not persisting while putting value in textbox persists.

XAML part of custom DataGrid

```
            <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgName" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="100" Visibility="Collapsed"/>


            <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgPredicates" Binding="{Binding Path=Predicate}" Header="Predicate" MinWidth="100"
                                           Visibility="Collapsed"/>



            <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" IsReadOnly="True"
                                                                Visibility="Collapsed" MaxWidth="80" Width ="*">
                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="../images/Delete.png" Height="15" Width="15"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TreeType}" Header="Tree Type" Width="50"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </WPFtoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </WPFtoolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ho you fill the grid with a data?

Comment: I filled the data by binding a DataTable

Comment: You mean like MyDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["MyColumn"] = "My Value";?

Comment: `TextBlock.Text` binding is `OneWay` by default. For a `TextBox` it is `TwoWay`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you want the changes that you make to the `TextBlock`/`TextBox` to be propagated to the underlying `DataTable`. This works for a `TextBox` but not for a `TextBlock`.

The reason for this is that `TextBox.Text` binds `TwoWay` by default but `TextBlock.Text` binds `OneWay`. If you want this to work you have to change all your `TextBlock` bindings to explicitly use `TwoWay` like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: actually i m doing stuff through C# code not through XAML so can u guide something in C# syntax

Comment: Sure, but I need to know how you create your Columns first. You can't modify a Binding that is in use so AutoGeneratedColumns won't work, you'll have to add it to the column style/template definition. Is it a `DataGridTextColumn` or `DataGridTemplateColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want  interest xaml , this code maybe work for yor need.
(xx ,yy is row and colonm number)

DataGridCell cell =(YourDgName.Columns[XX].GetCellContent(DgCagrilar.Items[YY])).Parent s DataGridCell;
                        if (cell.Background == Brushes.Pink)
                            cell.Background = Brushes.Plum;
                        else
                            cell.Background = Brushes.Pink;